# Is it possible to refresh specific view without performing dump to the entire views hierarhy tree with AndroidViewClient?

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient

I need a way to monitor some view parameters (for example to catch the moment it becomes enabled etc)

To do so I think I need the possibility to refresh single view because performing dump to the entire views hierarchy tree takes too much time.

Is it possible to refresh a specific view?

Is there any other way to monitor specific view parameters without performing dump to the entire views tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. `vc.dump()` is the way **AndroidViewClient** synchronizes the internal View tree representation with whatever is in the screen when called.

Comment: vc.dump() takes from 3 to 5 seconds for my application. This is not good enough for monitoring specific view parameter state. It would be very useful, very necessary if you can provide such function in the future versions. At lest for the situation when I know the specific view absolute id/no_id number (I can get the required view id/no_id number by performing dump once after starting the process. This will not change at lest till the process end)

Comment: The main feature of the application I'm trying to automate is to sample some sensors with selected sampling rate for a selected run time duration. So one of the main functions I want to automate is to measure the real run duration for each set duration for all possible sampling rates, for all possible variety of run durations. To do so I need to monitor some icon/button state (view attribute). If I can sample that icon only each 4-8 seconds by dumping the entire views hierarchy this is not good enough. I will be more than happy if someone could help me with this issue.